# Add fractional hours to a DateTime in php

Tags: php, datetime, timestamp, strtotime

I have a system which I need to add a certain amount of fractional hours.
I've been searching and this is what I got, by far it's the most accurate method, but still doesn't give me the answer I need

```
    function calculateHours($hours){

    $now =  new DateTime("2017-10-25 10:23:00");  
    $time = array();
    $time = explode(".", $hours);
    $time [1] += $time [0]*60;

    $now->modify("+".$time[1]." hours");

    return $now; 
}


$diff = 119.23;
$answer = calculateHours($diff);
echo $answer ->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

The answer that I want to reach is "2017-11-09 11:00:00" and I receive "2017-10-25 12:22:23" instead

Comment: It seems like several things are wrong with your question. When I run your code I get the result `2017-10-25 12:22:23`. So either the start date is incorrect or the amount of hours you want to add. Also when multiplying 119 by 60 this will calculate the **minutes**, but you are adding **seconds** (so multiply the hours with 3600 and the minutes with 60).

Comment: Just edited it, I only realized now that it was giving "2017-10-25" instead of "2017-11-09", and the amount of hours which I want to add is correct (as far as I can see).

Comment: what unit of time is `$diff = 119.23`?

Comment: Hours, just edited it on the code :)

Comment: @MathewSGon Still it doesn't add up. When you add `119.23` hours to `2017-10-25` it will only add about 5 days. So you will never get to `2017-11-09`.

Comment: @MathewSGon see my answer below

Comment: @MathewSGon where did you get the `119.23` number?

Comment: It's the amount of hours which my item is stored.

The item has an max amount which it can be out of it's place.
I was doing $maxTime - $diff and it gave me 241.13 (360.36 - 119.23).

Either it does get's an value so low or it gives a too high DateTime

Comment: 23 is the number of minutes or the percentage of an hour ?

Comment: number of hours

Comment: why do you store your hours as integers?

Comment: 119.23 is ~ 5 days so its impossible to reach your date

Comment: I re-did everything and used the max date, finally found it

(Just to explain it better: this amount of hours mentioned above -min, max or the difference between both- are stored in a database)

Answer (score 1):

Adding the hours is not correct. When you multiply hours times 60 it will make minutes.

This code should work.

```
function calculateHours($hours){

    $now =  new DateTime("2017-10-25 10:23:00");
    $time = explode(".", $hours);
    $time[1] += $time[0]*60;

    $now->modify("+".$time[1]." minutes");

    return $now;
}


$diff = 119.23;
$answer = calculateHours($diff);
echo $answer->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Result is `2017-10-30 09:46:00`

Comment: Yes, i got to this result, still thinking what can be wrong that my code doesn't get to the specified value

Comment: I changed `$now->modify("+".$time[1]." hours");` to `$now->modify("+".$time[1]." minutes");`

Answer (score 0):

Use [date_add](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-add.php)

```
date_add($now, date_interval_create_from_date_string($tempo[1]' hours'));
```

or as object:

```
 $now->add( DateInterval::createFromDateString($tempo[1].' hours'));
```

Comment: Down vote because his example use Object not procedural type

Comment: link only answer

Comment: @Mcsky same here

Answer (score 0):

You should use [DateInterval php class](http://php.net/manual/fr/class.dateinterval.php) to create an inverval with x seconds from your `$hours` variable.

Then you just have to use the [datetime add interval](http://php.net/manual/fr/datetime.add.php) method to modify your date

Please take a look a this example

```
function calculateHours($hours){

    $now       =  new DateTime("2017-10-25 10:23:00");  
    var_dump($now);
    $timeParts = explode(".", $hours);
    // Where 23 is a percentage of on hour
    $minutes   = $timeParts[0] * 60 + round($time[1] * 60 / 100);
    // Where 23 is the number of minutes
    $minutes   = $timeParts[0] * 60 + $time[1];

    $interval = new DateInterval(sprintf('PT%dM', $minutes));
    $now->add($interval);
    echo $now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    return $now; 
}
```

Comment: I didn't downvote but you probably got downvoted for posting manuals. Although the information inside may provide the answer, it's not a suitable answer for stackoverflow. Please add an example that works in OP's situation and you may see the votes change.